# datatable editable column width behaving strange for empty column

Tags: datatable, datatables, jeditable, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using datatable editable plugin. Everything is fine but while i try to edit any empty column of first row , column width is behaving strangely. For other rows every thing works fine.

[image]             [image]

Here is code snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/DataTableTest/TableEditAjaxRequest",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": false,
                "scrollX" : true,
                 "aoColumns": [
                              {  "sName": "MyID",
                              },
                               {
                                 "sName": "Operation",
                                }
                               ]
          ]
         }).makeEditable({ 
              "height": "100%",
            "width": "100%",   
                } 

         );

    });
```

Once I edit any column of first row , everything gets back to normal. Please help me.

Comment: any body have any clue about this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it, I had to just call fnAdjustColumnSizing() on table.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var oTable = $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/DataTableTest/TableEditAjaxRequest",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": false,
                "scrollX" : true,
                 "aoColumns": [
                              {  "sName": "MyID",
                              },
                               {
                                 "sName": "Operation",
                                }
                               ]
          ]
         }).makeEditable({ 
              "height": "100%",
            "width": "100%",   
                } 

         );
if ( oTable.length > 0 ) {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    }

    });
```